# Have one application execute an action when another application is given a command using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I know nothing about AppleScript, but I wonder if it could make my life easier: is there a way to write an AppleScript that tells Safari / Firefox / Chrome to refresh the current tab when I save a document in another application, say TextWrangler? Essentially, I want to map the <kbd>Command+S</kbd> keyboard shortcut to do two things at once in two separate applications.

If that’s not possible, can you script one application so that saving one file executes a command in another window in that same application?

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible approaches to implement this, but the most straightforward would probably be to create a script that executes all steps you need (i.e. save the document and refresh the window) and bind that to the <kbd>Cmd+S</kbd> keyboard combo in the triggering application.

What you need for this approach to work, is, in order:

1. **a method to bind a key combo to a script effective only in a specific application**. [OS X’ Automator Services](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/index.html) fit that bill: their scope can be restricted to a single application (select it in the “only in” drop down at the top of the workflow actions), and they can be assigned a shortcut in the Keyboard preference pane of System Preferences.
2. **a way to relay your commands to the applications they target**. AppleScript can help you in two different ways, depending on the fact if your applications are scriptable, i.e. if they have a scripting dictionary you can inspect in the AppleScript editor:

   - if they do, and their terminology includes the saving action for the editor on one side (most scriptable document based apps do so in the form `save <document>`), the page refreshing for the browser(s) on the other (Chrome has `reload <tab>`, Safari gets the same result via a JavaScript detour, i.e. `do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in <document>` – I don’t use Firefox), you are set.
   - if they do not, *GUI Scripting* might help, i.e. simulating a click on the right UI element (menu or toolbar) via `tell application "System Events" to tell process <your process> to click item x of menu y`.

   That script can then be embedded into the Automator workflow (in an “Run AppleScript” action, to be precise).

As you can see, a lot depends on the exact software you are using. if you are new to AppleScript and the above baffles you, I’d suggest spending a bit of time on [the AppleScript pages of Mac OS X Automation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/index.html) (where you’ll also find example scripts which will kick start you into things like GUI Scripting).

One final note: as of this writing, [sandboxed applications do not honor key combos assigned to them in the Keyboard Preference pane](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3203931?start=0&tstart=0) (they do honor **global** key combos set there – just not those specifically targeting them). This means you cannot, for instance, currently override TextEdit’s <kbd>Cmd+S</kbd> shortcut for saving in Lion. As long as your editor is not sandboxed (easily checked in Activity Monitor), you should have no issue with this.

Comment: The above being said while sticking to the original question’s AppleScript component, for the usage case outlined, you might want to check out [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) or [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll have to do some research now. I have discovered that I have an app that will do something very similar to what I want already, but it'll be interesting to see if I can accomplish the original goal. I actually found LiveReload while browsing the internet looking for apps that would do what I wanted. Haven't bought it yet, probably will though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a folder action to refresh the current tab when a new file is saved in the folder.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        tell window 1 to tell active tab
            set URL to (get URL)
        end tell
    end tell

end adding folder items to
```